# Using `this` in a forEach()

Tags: javascript, foreach

(Disclaimer: I'm in the process of learning JavaScript)
I have an object constructor like so:

```
var Palette = function() {
    this.colors = ["red", "green", "blue"];
    this.getColorCombinations = function() {
        var combos = [];
        this.colors.forEach(function(a) {
            this.colors.forEach(function(b) {
                if(a !== b) {
                    combos.push([a, b]);
                }
            });
        });
        return combos;
    };
}

var p = new Palette();
alert(JSON.stringify(p.getColorCombinations()));
```

With the expected output:

`[["red","green"],["red","blue"],["green","red"],["green","blue"],["blue","red"],["blue","green"]]`

After some research I realize now that this doesn't work because in the inner anonymous functions, "this" points to the global object and not the Palette instance anymore.

**My question is, what is the "JavaScript way" to deal with this?** I see similar problems solved with Apply, Bind, Call or simply assigning `this` to a variable, but so far I've not found any examples of which way is consistently best practice for referencing `this` in inner anonymous functions.

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/3po3mxkL/) is the JsFiddle. (I modified it to output to a div for easier text copying)

Comment: Depends on whether or not you transpile to support old browsers. Best solution is fat arrow functions:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions
second best is rossipedia's answer. Any professional js dev will likely be familiar with all of them.

Comment: …and the third best is `Function.prototype.bind`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass `this` as the second parameter to `forEach`

```
arr.forEach(callback, thisArg);
```

Per [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> `thisArg`:
>   Optional. Value to use as this when executing callback.

I've [updated your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/6gxtfzvv/1/) to show it's usage, but the gist is change this call:

```
this.colors.forEach(function(a) {
    this.colors.forEach(function(b) {
        if(a !== b) {
            combos.push([a, b]);
        }
    });
});
```

To this:

```
this.colors.forEach(function(a) {
    this.colors.forEach(function(b) {
        if(a !== b) {
            combos.push([a, b]);
        }
    });
}, this); // <- pass this as second arg
```

Also of note is that many other `Array.prototype` methods that accept a callback also support this idiom, including:

- `forEach`
- `map`
- `every`
- `some`
- `filter`

However, if you just need to specify what `this` is bound to when calling a function, and that function is *not* set as a property on the object, then probably the most idiomatic way would be with `Function.prototype.call()` or `Function.prototype.apply()`.

And if ES6 is available to you, then an arrow function would be even better, as it inherits `this` from the calling context:

```
this.colors.forEach(a => {
    this.colors.forEach(b => {
        if(a !== b) {
            combos.push([a, b]);
        }
    });
});
```